# Multi-byte character split generates junk symbols on saving to database

Tags: java, string, split, utf, multibyte

In my application, dynamic long strings are generated. these values I am saving in a database with a maximum length. when the maximum length is crossed, the string is split using a custom code and a new line gets inserted in database.

The problem here occurs when multi-byte characters are used. At the split of the string if a word is getting split at a Vowel signs (matra), then it generates a junk symbols like a **diamond with question mark in between**.

```
    int blockSize = 12;
    String str1 = "<SOME STRING>";

    byte[] b = str1.getBytes("UTF-8");    

    int loopCount = x; // in actual code dynamically generated
    String outString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= loopCount; i++) {
        if (i != loopCount) {
            outString = new String(b, i * blockSize, blockSize, "UTF-8");
        } else {
            outString =
                    new String(b, i * blockSize, (b.length - loopCount * blockSize));
        }
    }
```

1. How can I avoid splitting of string when in between a word and instead take to complete word to the next time.? 
   2.Or is there any other way for stopping generation of junk symbols.

Comment: can you store the raw bytes in the DB instead?

Comment: Hard to guess without knowing what custom code you use to split the string, what encoding you use internally and in the database... The junk symbol looks like an incorrect character for the used charset, but currently your question is unclear for lacking of essential information. As a hint: do not split a (multi-) byte string, but split a unicode string and adjust the length to have a correct length of the converted byte string. May be enough or not depending on encodings...

Comment: Hint 2: split using code points not code units (chars).

Comment: Have added a sample code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Text as conceived in Unicode has its problems on several levels.

As pure text composed from Unicode **code points**.
`ĉ` can be represented as one code point U+109, in UTF-16 (binary format) as one `char`'\u0109'`, or as`c`plus a zero-width so called combining diacritical mark for`^`. So splitting between code points already is problematic.`java.text.Normalizer` can normalize to either composed or decomposed form. Then there are the Left-To-Right and Right-To-Left markers to consider when using a part of a text.

On the **UTF-16** level, java `char`, some code points need 2 chars, a so called surrogate pair. This is testable in java using `Character`. The Character class and also regular expression `Pattern` has a rather good Unicode support. One can find categories like combining diacritical marks.

On the **UTF-8** level some (non-ASCII) chars or code points need multibyte sequences, so splitting a byte array causes UTF-8 illegal garbage at the split point.

***The solution?***

1. Maybe sensible to normalize text; mind file names.
2. Do not consider byte sub-arrays as valid text
3. Treat boundaries of byte arrays careful, even a `c` at the end might be `ĉ`, consider a shifting boundary buffer.